# TF400324 : Team foundation server not available from server (Some server IP). Technical information(for administrator):

Tags: tfs

While connecting to tfs server I am getting this issue.
"Team foundation server not available from server *.*.*.* (Some server IP). Technical information(for administrator): the underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive"

I am facing this issue in one machine but in other machine its working fine. and I am not using any VPN.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a firewall/port issue.  You can run WireShark (or something similiar) on both machines and compare the network route.  Then talk to you network admins about removing the block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much technical knowledge about TFS, but everyday i have to check-in my code from Visual Studio and recently i came across this issue. I tried a simpler way:

```
-> Logged out then logged in into the TFS again through Team-> Manage Connections.
-> Mapped my project again.
```

And Voila! it worked. Maybe this will help others